# How to refactor complicated logic in create_unique method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, refactoring

I would like to simplify this complicated logic for creating unique Track object.

```
def self.create_unique(p)
  f = Track.find :first, :conditions => ['user_id = ? AND target_id = ? AND target_type = ?', p[:user_id], p[:target_id], p[:target_type]]
  x = ((p[:target_type] == 'User') and (p[:user_id] == p[:target_id]))
  Track.create(p) if (!f and !x)
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a rewrite of with a few simple extract methods:

```
def self.create_unique(attributes)
  return if exists_for_user_and_target?(attributes)
  return if user_is_target?(attributes)

  create(attributes)
end

def self.exists_for_user_and_target?(attributes)
  exists?(attributes.slice(:user_id, :target_id, :target_type))
end

def self.user_is_target?(attributes)
  attributes[:target_type] == 'User' && attributes[:user_id] == attributes[:target_id]
end
```

This rewrite shows my preference for small, descriptive methods to help explain intent. I also like using guard clauses in cases like `create_unique`; the happy path is revealed in the last line (`create(attributes)`), but the guards clearly describe exceptional cases. I believe my use of `exists?` in `exists_for_user_and_target?` could be a good replacement for `find :first`, though it assumes Rails 3.

You could also consider using uniqueness active model validation instead.

Answer (score -1):

```
@@keys = [:user_id, :target_id, :target_type]
def self.create_unique(p)
  return if Track.find :first, :conditions => [
    @@keys.map{|k| "#{k} = ?"}.join(" and "),
    *@@keys.map{|k| p[k]}
  ]
  return if p[@@keys[0]] == p[@@keys[1]]
  return if p[@@keys[2]] == "User"
  Track.create(p)
end
```